# distinguish user data from parameter names in a query with placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am using a class to build a MySQL query with named parameters to bind the data to it. An example query might be.

```
INSERT INTO table (title, text) VALUES (?title, ?text)
```

Now you can specify values to use for those placeholders (`?title`, `?text`) by giving the parameter name and a value. In this process the value will be escaped (basically `mysql_real_escape_string` with special treatments for booleans, arrays and so on).

The problem is a value that contains placeholders itself because I replace them sequentially. To complete the example above the replacements could be as follows.

```
title -> "hey ?text"
text -> "lorem ipsum ..."
```

My first thoughts are to replace the placeholders with unique values first. Those must be strings that cannot occur in the escaped strings.

Is this a good way and what char-sequences exist for such a purpose?

Comment: How are you doing the string replacement?

Comment: Why aren't you using PDO for this?

Comment: @hafichuk Right now they are simple `str_ireplace` calls in a foreach loop. The parameters are saved in an associative array untill the final query is requested.

Comment: @Paul I am using my own class for MySQL connections and queries for some time now and just needed this little functionality. So I did not want to rewrite everything to PDO. The basic concept were a few lines of code. Actually i havent thought it will be that hard to find a save sequence for MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [mysqli_prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

What you would need to do is take your existing named parameters and replace them with only question marks. As you sequentially pull the named parameters out of the query string, you will be building an ordered array that you will use in your `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` function and place the appropriate value from your value array. Once the ordered array is built, you'll need to iterate over it and do type checks so you can pass the `$types` value into `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

**I'd highly recommend that you take a look at using a library like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in place of rolling your own.**

Comment: I am using named parameters to add them in any order I need. Also it looks very nasty when there are like 10 parameters in one function call. And yes there are solutions with arrays but i decided for these named parameters now. Additionally it is possible to use them multiple times.

Comment: I understand the purpose of using named parameters. If my answer wasn't clear, I was proposing that you could use existing PHP functions (mysqli_prepare and mysqli_stmt_bind_params) for the internals of your mysql class along with the logic that you could follow.

Comment: FYI, source code is available for the PDO library. It may give you some ideas on how to implement this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole concept is wrong I believe.
You are mixing matters.

A placeholder should be used only to add a value to a query. NOT to create fancy syntax.

Nothing prevent you from doing something like

$text = "lorem ipsum ...";
   $title = "hey $text";

so get your your variables ready this way.
and only then put them into query.

However, I may overlook some sensible issue. If you have some well-reasoned objection - I'll try to find a solution for you

as to the question in your title, I am just escaping ? with another ?? in my placeholder parser.

Comment: Your last sentence tells me you untderstood the question. Now what stops your users from entering "??" followed by a placeholder name used in your query? While you can imagine any fancy replacement that is unlikely to be accidently stumbled upon by a user I am searching for a value that makes it impossible. It is more of a theoretical thing. Later I found a solution that is highly reliant on the escape function used, but I am not too happy with that, which is why I haven't posted it.